# If a trigonometric series converges to a function $f$, is the Fourier series of $f$ the original series?

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, trigonometric-series

If a trigonometric series $\frac{1}{2}a_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n\cos(nx)+b_n\sin(nx))$ 
converges pointwise to a function $f$, then is the Fourier series of $f$ the original trigonometric series?

I know that if we have uniform convergence, then we can integrate term by term and the conclusion is true. But what if we only have pointwise convergence?

I appreciate any help!

Comment: If $f$ is Lebesgue integrable, the answer is yes (c.f. Zygmund's Trigonometric Series, vol. 1, Theorem IX (3.1)). Generally, though, $f$ need not be integrable. Counterexamples can be found in Gelbaum and Olmsted's *Counterexamples in Analysis*.

Comment: @DavidMitra And $f \cos(nx)$ is not necessarily integrable? This is very counterintuitive...